# how to load a function when I click on a button in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module

I'll be very grateful who can help me with this line I've this:
how to load a function when I click on a button
because now I have this but it does not work

```
export var Modulo = React.createClass({ 
    prom1: function () {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> CONTENT TWO</h1>
                <span  >Para vos bebe</span>
                <span onClick={this.prom2}> Hasta agotar existencias</span>
                <span onClick={this.prom3}>Promociones de la hora</span>
            </div>
        )   
    },
    prom2: function () {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> CONTENT TWO</h1>
                <span  onClick={this.prom1}>Para vos bebe</span>
                <span > Hasta agotar existencias</span>
                <span onClick={this.prom3}>Promociones de la hora</span>
            </div>
        )   
    },
    prom3: function () {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> CONTENT TREE</h1>
                <span onClick={this.prom1} >Para vos bebe</span>
                <span onClick={this.prom2}> Hasta agotar existencias</span>
                <span>Promociones de la hora</span>
            </div>
        )   
    },
    render: function() {
        return this.prom2();
    }
})
```

thanks

Comment: You need to keep state in your component and depending on the state, `render` will have to  call one if those methods. Having one of these methods be called as event handler doesn't make sense. Why would `render` magically return what the event handler returns? See the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use states instead of create three different methods with markup, like this

```
var Modulo = React.createClass({ 
  getInitialState: function () {
    var DEFAULT_TITLE = 'CONTENT One';

    return {
      title: DEFAULT_TITLE,

      links: [{
        link: 'Para vos bebe',
        title: DEFAULT_TITLE,
        isActive: true
      }, {
        link: 'Hasta agotar existencias',
        title: 'CONTENT TWO',
        isActive: false
      }, {
        link: 'Promociones de la hora',
        title: 'CONTENT THREE',
        isActive: false
      }]   
    }
  },

  handleClick: function(index) {
    var links = this.state.links.map((e, i) => {
      e.isActive = !!(i === index)
      return e;
    });

    this.setState({
      title: this.state.links[index].title,
      links: links
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    var links = this.state.links.map(function (link, index) {
      return <span 
        key={index}
        className={ link.isActive ? 'active' : '' }
        onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this, index) }
      >
        { link.link }
      </span>
    }, this);

    return <div>
      <h1>{ this.state.title }</h1>
      <div>{ links }</div>
    </div>
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/35088/)